# Get client time with JavaScript into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This array holds business hours for each day of the week, the problem is that after using PHP, I realized that I can not get the client side time and that I will need JavaScript for that.  Any idea if I can use some javascript code to get the client current time?

```
//business hours
$storeSchedule = [
    'Sun' => ['03:00 PM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Mon' => ['06:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Tue' => ['06:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Wed' => ['06:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Thu' => ['06:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Fri' => ['06:00 AM' => '09:00 PM'],
    'Sat' => ['09:00 AM' => '06:00 PM']
];

// current OR user supplied UNIX timestamp
$timestamp = time();

// default status
$status = 'closed';

// get current time object
$currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

// loop through time ranges for current day
foreach ($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

// create time objects from start/end times
$startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime);
$endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime);

// check if current time is within a range
if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
    $status = 'open';
    break;
    }
}

echo "is currently $status";
```

Comment: Why u want to use client's time for this?

Comment: What is the code to do with the question? Javascript/time/google - got http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Aren't your business hours according to *your* timezone?

Comment: I also think that using the client time is nonsense, as your shop or whatever will be open in you local time, not the time of the client

Comment: Sorry that you guys couldn't comprehend what I needed.  I did a work around for it and used **date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");** to set the timezone to the one I needed it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I unsterstand you right, you can call the client time with

`var date = new Date()`

and then send it with AJAX

Mike

Answer (score 2):

I do not exactly know you workflow, but I would use AJAX to do this. 
When the page loads, get the time in Javascript, and send it via AJAX to he PHP script.
PHP would process the time, and return the current state, which could be added to the page using JavaScript again

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clienttime = new Date();
  $.get( "your.php", {"time": clienttime}, function( data ) {
    alert( "Store is: " + data );
  });

});
```

In you PHP you only need to change the loading (and maybe parsing) of the time:

```
$currentTime = $_GET['time']; // get the time from the get params sent by ajax
```